# is this the correct way to install phpunit via puppet

Tags: phpunit, vagrant, puppet

I have been struggling today to install phpunit via puppet, I originally used pear but that clearly is the wrong way to install it according to the phpunit website. The only way I managed to get it working is via an exec. I am using CENTOS 6, Vagrant, Virtualbox and puppet. This is the command I am using, is there a better way to do this is my question.

```
exec { 'install phpunit' :
  command => '/usr/bin/wget -O /usr/local/bin/phpunit https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar',
  creates => '/usr/local/bin/phpunit'
}

exec { 'pchmod phpunit':
  command => '/bin/chmod +x /usr/local/bin/phpunit',
  require => Exec['install phpunit']
}
```

**update**

So I did some more reasearch and before December 2014 installing it via pear would of given you the error **http://pear.phpunit.de/ will be shut down no later than December, 31 2014.** so I am guessing the above method I am using is a good option but not sure if there is anything better.

*not sure why this got a down vote, maybe add a comment to better help the community ask questions*

Comment: `exec` is the common workaround if something is not natively supported. First point of order though: [Relevant Forge Modules](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/modules?utf-8=%E2%9C%93&sort=rank&q=phpunit)

Comment: ahhhh, I didn't know about Forge Modules. you might of just made my day :) thanks!